# Pause horizontal scrolling in chart.js for real time data

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am working on chart.js plugin with real time chart so i want to pause scrolling chart but when i calling pause dynamically its not working.

```
pausestart:boolean;

plugins: {
      streaming: {
          onRefresh: function(chart: any) {
            chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset: any) {
              dataset.data.push({
                x: Date.now(),
                y: Math.random()
              });
            });
          },
          duration: 12000,
          refresh: 100,
          delay: 1000,
          frameRate: 60,
          pause: this.pausestart
        }
      }
```

i am setting `pausestart`initially false after click on pause button set it to true

```
pause() {
    this.pausestart = true;
  }

  start() {
    this.pausestart = false;
  }
```

how can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a `BaseChartDirective` using `@ViewChild`, then use the `chart` property to set the `pause` option and call `update()`.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;

  pause() {
    this.chart.chart.options.plugins.streaming.pause = true;
    this.chart.chart.update({duration: 0});
  }

  start() {
    this.chart.chart.options.plugins.streaming.pause = false;
    this.chart.chart.update({duration: 0});
  }

  ...
```

Comment: Awesome @nagix i have missed to include chart object. Now its working thank you.